# Filtering ARRAY and grabbing distinct entry

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I am collecting a count of desktop and mobile devices...  the count is coming back correctly based in the items total in the `ARRAY`. But, now I need to remove duplicates... Example `user_id = 001` can have 10 entries for IOS ... so I would need to do something like ... `IF $row['last_login'] Date()` is the most current then grab that entry and count as 1. End result for user_id = 001 would be 1 entry count and not 10 (which I am getting now).

```
if ($results = $dbh->runQuery($sql)) {
    foreach ($results as $key=>$row){ 
        $users[$row['user_id']][] = array('user_id'=>$row['user_id'],
            'racid' => $row['racid'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'last_login' => $row['last_login'],
            'fname' => $row['fname'],
            'lname' => $row['lname'],
            'role_id' => $row['role_id'],
            'role_name' => $row['role_name'],
            'ios_device_token' => $row['ios'],
            'roid_device_token' => $row['roid'],
            'p_name' => $row['p_name']);

            if($row['ios'] !== null && $row['ios'] !== '' && $row['ios'] !== '-1'){
                $ios_count++;
            }

            if($row['android'] !== null && $row['android'] !== '' && $row['android'] !== '-1'){
                $android_count++;
            }

        $invalidValues = [null, "", -1];

        if(in_array($row['ios'], $invalidValues) && in_array($row['android'], $invalidValues)){
            $desktop_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your `$sql` definition? It might be more efficient if you re-structure your query to eliminate duplicates on the way in.

Comment: @esqew I thought about that but, another part of my could needs SQL to grab all entries for a User because role_id and p_name have multiple entries that need to be grouped together for a user. So in this case all 10 rows would need to be grabbed taking away the role_id and p_name from each. I will research some more about a query option. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using associative arrays, you can "distinctify" by your own criterium. Something like the following code.

However what @esqew said (commenting your question) about altering the SQL instead of the PHP is probably a cleaner angle, especially since PHP is generally quite slow.

```
if ($results = $dbh->runQuery($sql)) { // that exists already
  $latestEntries = []; // assoc. array: key=user, value=row
  foreach ($results as $row) { // that exists already
    // assuming 'last_login' is a timestamp or any format that can be used in inequality
    // otherwise cook your own comparison function
    if (
      !$latestEntries[$row['user_id']]
      || $latestEntries[$row['user_id']]['last_login'] < $row['user_id']['last_login']
    ) {
      $latestEntries[$row['user_id']] = $row;
    }
    // rest of your code that exists already
  }
  // here, after the loop, $latestEntries has the latest entry for each user found in $results
}
```